# Object Location Changes when rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I made a scene where a grenade bounces in and rolls across the floor, except the issue is when I render it the location changes slightly. I am running blender 2.78 with supported features only. I have turned all modifiers off and restarted blender. The problem still persists. Can anyone help me out?

Note: I made the animation by baking a physics simulation to key frames. The room was also made by archimesh. (I have tried disabling archimesh in the user preferences but it didn't change anything)

In the viewport it looks like this:

[image]

In the render it looks like this:
[image]

Notice in the bottom right that the grenade has not changed locations. To my eye it looks like the grenade is in the same place, but the floor has changed locations. But either way, I do not know why this is happening. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Cycles dislacement?

Comment: If you are talking about the modifier, there isn't one on the floor. All the floor modifiers are turned off. If you are talking about the material, I have only supported features turned on.

Comment: Yes, I meant the material displacement. Try to remove everthing from your file except for placeholder object and upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, possibly?

Comment: Place holder object?

Comment: Just a condensed version of the scene, so no one steals your materials and the file size is small.

Comment: Edited question, I just uploading the whole .blend without any textures packed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden object in your scene.

Since it only has restrict viewport visibility turned "on" you can only see it in the render.

To unhide all press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the 3D viewport.

Or locate the hidden object in the outliner and delete it or restrict rendering for it as well.

[image]